# Batch folder of images into grayscale using php

Tags: php, batch-file, gd

Can anyone spot where I'm going wrong here. It should be creating grayscale copies of images in one folder and saving them in another folder. Could it be to do with the way im referencing the file locations. Folder permissions on both folders are 777. Script is running without visible error but no images are being created.

```
function grayscalecopy($targetfile, $outputfile){
$size = GetImageSize($targetfile);
$width = $size[1];
$height = $size[0];
$canvas = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
$sourceimage = imagecreatefromjpeg($targetfile);
imagefilter($sourceimage, IMG_FILTER_GRAYSCALE);
imagecopy($canvas, $sourceimage, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height);
imagejpeg($canvas, $outputfile, 95);
imagedestroy($sourceimage);
imagedestroy($canvas);
echo "Converted ".$targetfile." to grayscale as ".$outputfile." ".$width."x".$height."<br/>";
}

$serverfiles = glob("artworkimages/thumbs/*.*");
//$numbertocache = count($serverfiles);
$numbertocache = 10;
for ($i=0; $i<$numbertocache; $i++)
{
    $serverfilesshort=explode("/",$serverfiles[$i]);
    $serverfilesshort=$serverfilesshort[count($serverfilesshort)-1];
    grayscalecopy($serverfiles[$i], "artworkimages/thumbs/grays/".$serverfilesshort);
}
```

Comment: What is the specific issue you're seeing? Please edit your answer and describe the problem.

Comment: Script is running without visible error but no images are being created.

Comment: Do you see a number of "Converted xxx to grayscale as yyy 123x456" lines in the output?

Comment: Yes with the correct path information for the two files aswell
eg "Converted artworkimages/thumbs/4753.jpg to grayscale as artworkimages/thumbs/grays/4753.jpg 120x93"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for the result of the `imagejpeg` call. Change your code to:

```
$result = imagejpeg($canvas, $outputfile, 95);
if($result)
{
    echo "Converted ".$targetfile." to grayscale as ".$outputfile." ".$width."x".$height."<br/>";
}
else
{
    echo "Could not save to $outputfile.<br>"
    if(!is_writable($outputfile)
        echo "The path was not writable";
}
imagedestroy($sourceimage);
imagedestroy($canvas);
```

This will help us see what's going on. If you get "The path was not writable", try using absolute paths instead of relative paths, for example:

```
grayscalecopy($serverfiles[$i], dirname(__FILE__)."/artworkimages/thumbs/grays/".$serverfilesshort);
```